# WPF - When TextBox inside DateTemplate is focused change datatemplate child property

Tags: wpf, listview, triggers

I have a listview with a Border wrapping a textbox (and other elements not shown in sample code). I want when the textbox is keyboard focused to change a property of the border that wraps it.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding activeLists}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="border">
                    <TextBox Text="something">
                        <TextBox.Style>
                            <Style>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="TextBox.IsFocused" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBox.Style>
                    </TextBox>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

If using inside the trigger TargetName="border" the item is not found.
If possible to do this from XAML only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried running this, I also got the error "TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter". Which indicates that you can't set a property of the Border control inside a style setter for the TextBox control (which doesn't honestly surprise me.)

What you can do instead is set it in the style of the border control itself, using a DataTrigger to bind to the IsFocused property of the textbox:

```
<Border>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsFocused, ElementName=textBox}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <TextBox Name="textBox" Text="something"/>
</Border>
```